# Phrase equivalent to It's a piece of cake

Tags: classical-latin, idiom

I'm looking for a Latin phrase that means "very easy", something idiomatic like "It's a piece of cake", or "It's like taking candy from a baby".

Any ideas?

Comment: Good question! I don't know of a colorful Latin idiom for that purpose, but you can use the adjective *perfacilis* before you find one.

Comment: There's a good expression for the opposite: *Facilius sit Nili caput invenire.* = "It would be easier to find the source of the Nile."

Answer (score 4):

When my dictionary was written. it was not "as easy as falling off a chair;" try possibly= *sicut declinans de clino* nor even "like a knife through butter;" try possibly= *facile, sicut culter per butyrum.* But here is the authentic idiomatic entry:

> **As easy as kiss my hand,** *declive; facillime; nullo negotio* (Ainsworth)

*nullo negotio* is a business term; 'no great trouble.' The phrase is used by Cicero,

> *Nihil esse negotii  probatur,* 'I suppose it to be a very easy matter.'

and Plautus,

> *Neque de hac re negotium est, quin male occidam;* 'In this matter all things ran smoothly to my destruction.'

Comment: Could you specify what dictionary you are citing? Also: I think it's worth noting that the bolded part is an (antiquated) **English** idiom which is translated by pretty vanilla Latin equivalents. While useful, I don't think these quite qualify as idioms.

Comment: @brianpck, Ainsworth *Latin-English Dictionary* (Rivington, London) archive.org/details/ainsworthslatind00ains  Negotium commonly means *business affairs;* so *nullo negotio* is as close to an idiom as I could get.  "No hassle."

Answer (score 3):

There is actually a pretty good equivalent:

**Tam facile quam pirum volpes comest.** (as easy as a fox eats a pear).

Originally from [Plautus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:abo:phi,0119,013:3:1#note1):

> tam facile vinces quam pirum volpes comest.

There might be an ambiguity in this expression as the [footnote](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0104%3Aact%3D3%3Ascene%3D1#note1) in my linked doc suggests (However, it seems most sources does treat this as "as easy .."):

> This may either mean, very easily indeed, or not at all. It is not clear that a fox will eat a pear; but if he does, his teeth will go through it with the greatest ease. Not improbably, Tranio uses the expression for its ambiguity.

---

A second option of the same style is to be found in [Seneca The Younger](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A2007.01.0028%3Asection%3D10)

> **Tam facile, quam canis adsidit.** (as easily as a dog sits down)

---

Yet, another possible (however violent) suggestion to describe something that should be easily done would be **plumbeo gladio jugulare**:

> cum illum plumbeo gladio iugulatum iri tamen diceret.  (saying that a leaden sword was good enough to cut his throat.) [Cic.](http://perseus.uchicago.edu/perseus-cgi/citequery3.pl?dbname=LatinAugust2012&query=Cic.%20Att.%201.16&getid=0) [trans](http://perseus.uchicago.edu/perseus-cgi/citequery3.pl?dbname=LatinAugust2012&query=Cic.%20Att.%201.16&getid=1).

[L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=gladius&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) reckons this as a proverb (I think it is proverbial in Cic. already) and assigned this meaning: "with very little trouble", which I think might fit here.

So just to retain the same tempo/stance of the English "It's a piece of cake", maybe (having no attestation whatsoever) one can shorten a bit and say simply: **(cum) plumbeo gladio**- the full proverb will be implied here. Example: "tam facile est! plumbeo gladio queo facere"

- it is not exactly parallel to the English "It's like taking candy from a baby", since here is a description of the amount of energy should be invested in order to make a thing happen (rather than the act itself): "with dull sword" i.e with quite weak sword.