# How do you say "5 times easier than" or "x times easier" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, comparative

I put in [packhum](https://latin.packhum.org/search) `#bis# ~ difficil`.

And nothing came up, same with 'facil'.  I looked in the L&S dictionary under 'totiens' hoping that would shed some light but it did not.  Perhaps the Romans didn't think of expressing degrees of difficulty with numbers, so how else do you express degrees of goodness, easiness, etc.

Comment: One option is to use *tanto* + adv of the times. ***ter tanto** peior ipsa est quam illam tu esse vis.* (Pl.Per.153). Note that for twice, one can use *bis tanto*, but *altero tanto* is another option. I don't know if it was ever used to describe degrees of difficulty. One may find some value in [this](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4179/phrase-equivalent-to-its-a-piece-of-cake) question.

Comment: Thanks .........

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the English "5 times easier than" the number 5 doesn't usually seem to refer to anything concrete or easily measurable.
Therefore I'd regard it as an idiom rather than an actual numerical comparison.
I see no difference between "flying is ten times harder than driving" and "flying is much harder than driving".
(If you do, please elaborate on what the difference it. I don't think ease or difficulty can be meaningfully boiled down to a number.)

To compare degrees of difficulty, ease, and other such things, you just need to add one the many possible adverbs to the comparatives.
For example: *multo facilius* or *paulo melior*.
Latin does not seem to have idioms with numerical comparisons.

You can also take a look at [the "piece of cake" question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4179/79) and see if something there could be modified to work in your case.

If you want to know how to say "Livia has 5 times more money than Maria", then an actual numerical comparison is needed.
Any discussion of that should be taken to a separate question, though, as it is quite different from what you asked about here.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that.

Comment: @bobsmith76 You're welcome! I'm glad to be able to help.